# React table - how to merge 2 tables if the value of specific column is the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have 2 tables as shown below with below data.

```
  const callData = [
    { id: 1, type: "call", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
    { id: 2, type: "call", strike: 5000, volume: 30000 },
    { id: 3, type: "call", strike: 7000, volume: 20000 }
  ];

  const putData = [
    { id: 1, type: "put", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
    { id: 2, type: "put", strike: 5000, volume: 10000 },
    { id: 3, type: "put", strike: 7000, volume: 7000 }
  ];
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to combine these 2 tables together and arrange them based on the value of `strike`.
For example, if the strike of the object for call and put is the same, they will be in the same row like

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

is it possible in `react-table`?

App.js

````
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Type",
            accessor: "type"
          },
          {
            Header: "Volume",
            accessor: "volume"
          },
          {
            Header: "Strike",
            accessor: "strike"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  // got below data from async request
  const callData = [
    { id: 1, type: "call", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
    { id: 2, type: "call", strike: 5000, volume: 30000 },
    { id: 3, type: "call", strike: 7000, volume: 20000 }
  ];

  const putData = [
    { id: 1, type: "put", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
    { id: 2, type: "put", strike: 5000, volume: 10000 },
    { id: 3, type: "put", strike: 7000, volume: 7000 }
  ];

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={callData} />
      <Table columns={columns} data={putData} />
    </Styles>
  );
}

export default App;

Codesandbox<br>
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-monad-syq5h?file=/src/App.js:0-2533
```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8IXl.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqyKs.png
````

Comment: How you would like to display them in one row? Like each column has 2 texts? or you want to merge data and display the sum

Comment: @Eduard Each column has 2 texts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do preprocessing before displaying data?

You can put all records into one mutual way, arrange them as you need (filter and sort) and pass into one mutual table.